# RestKit 2.0 : Mapping - second entitiy nil when not unique

Tags: cocoa, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map an array of 'Comments' to a Comment entity that has a sub-entity 'testUser', the person who wrote the comment. Everything is mapping fine as long as the testUsers for all comments are unique.

If a user writes two comments, the second comment will have a nil testUser object. RestKit is mapping the second comment's testUser to the same object as the first testUser, even they belong to two seperate comment-objects. You can see this in the mapping results below. 
How can I avoid this happening?

Many many thanks. Al

// **Test one mapping result**

Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'user' to 'testUser'. 
Value:  (entity: TestUser; id: **0x17e1a070**  ; data: {

```
comment = "0x17e4d9b0 <x-coredata:///Comment/tC0FCC2A0-6B2A-4130-A711-6E4A983D40F258>";
testFirstName = Sam;
testID = 183599;
testLastName = Doe;
```

})

// **Test two mapping result**

Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'user' to 'testUser'. 
Value:  (entity: TestUser; id: **0x17e1a070**  ; data: {

```
comment = "0x15e72aa0 <x-coredata://5038C2F2-93CF-46BF-BB2A-66F2423FA2DE/Comment/p46>";
testFirstName = Sam;
testID = 183599;
testLastName = Doe;
```

})

// **Comments Mapping result**

2013-11-23 11:45:42.689 app[4619:8333] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:722 Mapped `NSSet` relationship object from keyPath 'items' to 'items'. Value: 
{(

(entity: Comment; id: 0x15eb9660  ; data: {

```
commentId = 407381;
createdAt = "2013-11-23 10:45:13 +0000";
testUser = "0x17e1a070 <x-coredata://5038C2F2-93CF-46BF-BB2A-66F2423FA2DE/TestUser/p9>";

text = "Test one";
```

}),
     
(entity: Comment; id: 0x17e4d9b0  ; 
data: {

```
commentId = 407382;
createdAt = "2013-11-23 10:45:30 +0000";
testUser = nil;
text = "Test two";
```

})
)}

// **Entities**

**Commments** (with relationship to)-> **Comment** (with relationship t0)-> **TestUser**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You haven't shown mappings, and I'm assuming that you have a to-many relationship to support what you're trying to do.*

When you create the relationship mapping you need to set the `assignmentPolicy` property to `RKUnionAssignmentPolicy`. The default policy replaces any existing connection with the new one. This policy will merge the connections instead.