# RestKit nested relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Working with RestKit, I'm trying to map the following JSON.

```
{
  "userID": 1,
  "collections": [
    {
      "collectionID": 120,
      "friends": [
        {
          "friendID": 6,
          "orders": [
            {
              "orderID": 1,
              "name": "Small"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "collectionID": 123,
      "friends": [
        {
          "friendID": 6,
          "orders": [
            {
              "orderID": 2,
              "name": "Medium"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm utilising RestKit and MagicalRecord - setup code, mapping and relationships below

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];

[managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:nil];
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure MagicalRecord to use RestKit's Core Data stack
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:3500"]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

RKEntityMapping *appMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"App" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
appMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userID" ];

RKEntityMapping *collectionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Collection" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
collectionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"collectionID" ];
[collectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"collectionID"]];

RKEntityMapping *friendMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Friend" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
friendMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"friendID" ];
[friendMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"friendID"]];

RKEntityMapping *orderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
orderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"orderID" ];
[orderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"orderID", @"name"]];


RKRelationshipMapping *appCollectionRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"collections" toKeyPath:@"collections" withMapping:collectionMapping];
[appMapping addPropertyMapping:appCollectionRelationship];

RKRelationshipMapping *collectionFriendRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"friends" toKeyPath:@"friends" withMapping:friendMapping];
[collectionMapping addPropertyMapping:collectionFriendRelationship];

RKRelationshipMapping *friendsOrderRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"orders" toKeyPath:@"orders" withMapping:orderMapping];
[friendsOrderRelationship setAssignmentPolicy:RKUnionAssignmentPolicy];
[friendMapping addPropertyMapping:friendsOrderRelationship];
```

Then, querying the /test route on my API (which outputs the JSON block above) with the below console out...

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:appMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/test" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    App *app = [mappingResult firstObject];
    for (Collection *collection in app.collections) {
        NSLog(@"collectionID = %@", collection.collectionID);
        for (Friend *friend in collection.friends) {
            NSLog(@"friendID = %@", friend.friendID);
            for (Order *order in friend.orders) {
                NSLog(@"Name = %@", order.name);
            }
        }
    }
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

Provides the following output - notice both Name's are Medium, not one Small and the other Medium.

```
collectionID = 120
friendID = 6
Name = Medium
Name = Small
collectionID = 123
friendID = 6
Name = Medium
Name = Small
```

Why would this be happening? I'm going to guess that it's because both friend ID's are the same, even though they're under different collections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have `identificationAttributes = @[ @"friendID" ];` and the default relationship connection rule for relationships rather than replacement. So, the second mapping finds the friend created by the first mapping and replaces the order relationship contents.

You can't realistically change the unique identifier based on the JSON you show, but you might want to examine that (in relation to your object graph requirements).

Also / alternatively, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162007/restkit-2-0-mapping-second-entitiy-nil-when-not-unique) for details of how to change the relationship assignment policy so that the original relationship contents aren't lost.

Comment: thanks for your input! So I should remove the ```friendMapping.identificationAttributes``` and change the current relationship code to ```RKRelationshipMapping *collectionFriendRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"friends" toKeyPath:@"friends" withMapping:orderMapping]; [collectionFriendRelationship setAssignmentPolicy:RKUnionAssignmentPolicy];``` I didn't even know about the AssignmentPolicy!

Comment: `assignmentPolicy` change on its own may be enough, it depends what objects you want in the model, what you consider to be a duplicate...

Comment: Doesn't that mean it'll union the two (potentially more) Name items? See edited code (just the relationships down the bottom)

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to decide what you want, union / 'duplicates'

Comment: Hmmm - well either option isn't that useful, as I need to have only one Name (among other properties - this is just a simplified use case). I think I might look at extracting the Orders out from the Friend objects, and just have an index pointing to the corresponding Order for that Friend. Unless I'm missing something? Thanks :)

Comment: You could use a transformable attribute on your entity and store the names as an array instead of a relationship to another entity...

Comment: I actually did that initially - but wasn't sure if that was the particularly 'right' way to do it. Was just interested to see what the general consensus was about modelling the given data! I think I'll relook at how its structured...