# RestKit - use identificationAttributes that are not part of the response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

In RestKit is it possible to use identificationAttributes that are actually not part of the JSON response?

My case is the following - I have a service that lists all articles for the currently logged-in user like `http://example.com/json/articles.json`

My problem is the following - since the application allows multiple users to login, I keep the articles in the database together with the userId for each article. If I set the `articleMapping.identificationattributes = @["articleId"]`, then I have a problem if two users using the device have the same article - it will be overwritten regardless of the userId, because it is not part of the response.

To sum up the facts:

- For the JSON request I do not send the userId, it is part of the
  server session only, so I think that I cannot use `RKRoute`
- I do the mapping of the article with the user manually after RestKit mapping.
- I do not have the userId property as part of the JSON response, it exists only inside the ArticleManagedObject.

Is there a way to inform RestKit that during the mapping, it should check the `articleId+userId` combination as an identificator? I tried using identificationPredicate with no success.

**EDIT:**

An example response from the server, when UserA is logged in:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "articles":[  
         {  
            "articleId":1,
            "title":"Objective C Basics"
         },
         {  
            "articleId":2,
            "title":"Xcode Basics"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and here is the response when UserB is logged in:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "articles":[  
         {  
            "articleId":1,
            "title":"Objective C Basics"
         },
         {  
            "articleId":3,
            "title":"Java Basics"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If UserA logs in, everything is fine. But if UserB logs in from the same device, then article 1 is mapped to UserB, and from now on, the connection between UserA and article 1 is lost.

As I understand from your suggestion, the only solution is to return also the user id from the service, set RKUnionAssignmentPolicy and let RestKit take care of the mapping (currently I am manually making the mapping between articles and users after RestKit).

Another question that I have - is it possible to set the identificationAttributes or identificationPredicate so that it makes a separation between object article 1 for UserA and object article 1 for UserB.

Comment: Are the articles for each user (with the same id) the same? Can you just use a to-many relationship?

Comment: The user-article relation is many-to-many, but the service returns only the articles for the current session user. My relation between user and article can be named "isReading" for better understanding. Many users can be reading the same article and one user can be reading many articles.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162007/restkit-2-0-mapping-second-entitiy-nil-when-not-unique and see if it helps

Comment: I have updated my question to better explain the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

You currently do the user to article mapping outside RestKit, this is fine, but you will need to modify this process a little.

To begin with, I'm assuming here that the article response is the full set of articles for the user. If not then things get more tricky and you'll need to modify the below to account:

Start by getting all of the existing articles for a user. With this we're going to look at what needs to be removed and what needs to be added.

As we iterate through the articles we have received we can check the existing articles for a match, if we find one we have no work to do. If we don't find a match we need to add the relationship to the existing set, which will be a union with any relationship to any other user.

Next we want to remove the list of new articles from the list of the existing articles to get the list of deletions, for these we just need to break the link, again leaving other users unchanged.