# RestKit 0.24 mapping using addConnectionForRelationship

Tags: restkit, foreign-key-relationship

It's been days i'm struggling with this relationship connection.

Data model

[image]

I have the following json:

```
{
"response":{
"pageInfo":[
],
"threads":{
"userId":"1",
"threadId":"58",
"status":"",
"timestamp":"2015-02-03T13:24:29.000Z",
"messages":[
{
"messageId":"23",
"threadId":"58",
"participantId":"106",
"text":"test",
"status":"",
"timestamp":"2015-02-03 13:24:29"
}
],
"participants":[
{
"participantId":"106",
"threadId":"58",
"userId":"1",
"user":{
"id":"1",
"username":"admin",
"email":"admin@go-surfin.com",
"medias":[
{
"id":"181",
"userId":"1",
"serviceName":"surfin",
"serviceURL":"http:\/\/media.go-surfin.com\/",
"mimeType":"image\/jpeg",
"size":"43505",
"width":"480",
"height":"320",
"filename":"c5564a10-f950-4398-a655-c9b31a0e8500.jpeg",
"url":"uploads\/avatar\/c5564a10-f950-4398-a655-c9b31a0e8500.jpeg",
"name":"",
"type":"AVATAR",
"status":"APPROUVED",
"comments":[
],
"likeIds":[
],
"timestamp":"2015-01-28T07:53:03.000Z"
}
],
"stats":{
"userId":"1",
"followers":2,
"followings":3,
"medias":3,
"trips":0,
"spots":506
},
"profile":{
"country":"FR",
"type":"SURFER",
"pro":"0"
},
"social":{
"facebook":"",
"youtube":"",
"twitter":"",
"instagram":""
},
"created":"2014-09-10T11:05:08.000Z",
"followingIds":[
"23",
"19",
"3"
],
"settings":[
{
"id":"17",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.newspot",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-12T16:52:20.000Z"
},
{
"id":"18",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.newcontest",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-05T15:56:22.000Z"
},
{
"id":"19",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.newmessage",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-04T09:14:29.000Z"
},
{
"id":"20",
"userId":"1",
"type":"metrics",
"key":"metrics.speed",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2015-01-25T17:57:31.000Z"
},
{
"id":"22",
"userId":"1",
"type":"metrics",
"key":"metrics.distance",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-30T11:17:31.000Z"
},
{
"id":"23",
"userId":"1",
"type":"metrics",
"key":"metrics.length",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-08T09:40:07.000Z"
},
{
"id":"24",
"userId":"1",
"type":"metrics",
"key":"metrics.forecast",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-30T11:17:31.000Z"
},
{
"id":"25",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.commentspot",
"value":"0",
"timestamp":"2014-11-12T16:52:20.000Z"
},
{
"id":"26",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.newplace",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-10T13:06:38.000Z"
},
{
"id":"27",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.mediaplace",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-10T17:37:30.000Z"
},
{
"id":"28",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.mediacontest",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-10T17:37:46.000Z"
},
{
"id":"30",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.mediaspot",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-11T08:41:50.000Z"
},
{
"id":"31",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.newtrip",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2015-01-16T14:13:37.000Z"
},
{
"id":"32",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.mediatrip",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-11T08:53:17.000Z"
},
{
"id":"33",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.jointrip",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2014-12-11T08:54:42.000Z"
},
{
"id":"36",
"userId":"1",
"type":"notifications",
"key":"notifications.commentplace",
"value":"1",
"timestamp":"2015-01-31T17:26:22.000Z"
}
],
"favorites":{
"userId":"1",
"placeIds":[
],
"spotIds":[
"4698"
],
"contestIds":[
],
"tripIds":[
]
},
"likes":{
"userId":"1",
"placeIds":[
],
"spotIds":[
],
"contestIds":[
],
"tripIds":[
],
"feedbackIds":[
],
"mediaIds":[
],
"statusIds":[
]
}
},
"status":"CREATOR",
"timestamp":"2015-02-03 13:20:33"
},
{
"participantId":"107",
"threadId":"58",
"userId":"2",
"user":{
"id":"2",
"username":"lgriffie",
"email":"lgriffie@go-surfin.com",
"medias":[
{
"id":"179",
"userId":"2",
"serviceName":"surfin",
"serviceURL":"http:\/\/media.go-surfin.com\/",
"mimeType":"image\/jpeg",
"size":"18808",
"width":"212",
"height":"212",
"filename":"a0de6758-97ac-4b84-9fae-e33b614640f0.jpeg",
"url":"uploads\/avatar\/a0de6758-97ac-4b84-9fae-e33b614640f0.jpeg",
"name":"",
"type":"AVATAR",
"status":"APPROUVED",
"comments":[
],
"likeIds":[
],
"timestamp":"2014-09-10T19:27:05.000Z"
}
],
"stats":{
"userId":"2",
"followers":1,
"followings":2,
"medias":1,
"trips":0,
"spots":0
},
"profile":{
"country":"US",
"type":"FOLLOWER",
"pro":"0"
},
"social":{
"facebook":"",
"youtube":"",
"twitter":"",
"instagram":""
},
"created":"2014-09-10T19:27:05.000Z",
"followingIds":[
"3",
"1"
]
},
"status":"NORMAL",
"timestamp":"2015-02-03 13:20:33"
}
],
"setting":{
"settingId":"7",
"threadId":"58",
"notification":"0",
"block":"0",
"timestamp":"2015-02-03 13:20:33"
}
},
"apiMethod":"threads:new"
}
}
```

Here is the defined mapping for each entity

THREAD

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"threadId":           @"threadId",
                                                    @"userId":             @"userId",
                                                    @"status":             @"status",
                                                    @"timestamp":          @"timestamp"
                                                    }];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"threadId" ];

[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"messages" toKeyPath:@"messages" withMapping:[AOThreadMessage mapping]]];
[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"participants" toKeyPath:@"participants" withMapping:[AOThreadParticipant mapping]]];
[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"setting" toKeyPath:@"setting" withMapping:[AOThreadSetting mapping]]];

[entityMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"user" connectedBy:@{ @"userId": @"userId" }];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];

return entityMapping;
}

+ (RKResponseDescriptor *)responseDescriptor
{
    return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[AOThread mapping]
                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST | RKRequestMethodGET
                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                       keyPath:@"response.threads"
                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
}
```

THREAD MESSAGE

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"messageId":          @"messageId",
                                                    @"participantId":      @"participantId",
                                                    @"text":               @"text",
                                                    @"status":             @"status",
                                                    @"timestamp":          @"timestamp"
                                                    }];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"messageId" ];

[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"media" toKeyPath:@"media" withMapping:[AOMedia mapping]]];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];

return entityMapping;
}

+ (RKResponseDescriptor *)responseDescriptor
{
    return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[AOThreadMessage mapping]
                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST | RKRequestMethodGET
                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                       keyPath:@"response.messages"
                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
}
```

THREAD PARTICIPANTS

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"participantId":      @"participantId",
                                                    @"userId":             @"userId",
                                                    @"status":             @"status",
                                                    @"timestamp":          @"timestamp"
                                                    }];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"participantId" ];

[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:[AOUser mapping]]];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];

return entityMapping;
}

+ (RKResponseDescriptor *)responseDescriptor
{
    return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[AOThreadParticipant mapping]
                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST | RKRequestMethodGET
                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                       keyPath:@"response.participants"
                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
}
```

THREAD SETTING

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"settingId":          @"settingId",
                                                    @"notification":       @"notification",
                                                    @"block":              @"block",
                                                    @"timestamp":          @"timestamp"
                                                    }];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"settingId" ];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];

return entityMapping;
}

+ (RKResponseDescriptor *)responseDescriptor
{
    return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[AOThreadSetting mapping]
                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST | RKRequestMethodGET
                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                       keyPath:@"response.setting"
                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
}
```

The AOThreadMessage thread relationship is nil. Other relationships are correctly set.

```
<AOThreadMessage: 0x7fa529a694d0> (entity: AOThreadMessage; id: 
0xd00000000004001c <x-coredata://23C60BAE-57BD-4904-BF7B-7D550DE13190/AOThreadMessage/p1> ; data: {
    address = nil;
    media = nil;
    messageId = 20;
    participantId = 106;
    status = "";
    text = test;
    thread = nil;
    timestamp = "2015-02-03 13:20:33 +0000";
})
```

For those who want to see the complete RestKit data mapping logs, just click here http://cloud.appsido.com/qN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains everything, so you need no foreign key mappings. Indeed having them could be causing your problem and resulting in only the last item actually being added to the relationship (because the default is replace not union). So, remove all the foreign key mappings that will be used here.

You don't show your data model but `participants`, `messages` and `setting` should all be bi-directional where the inverse relationship is called `thread` and then everything should work ok (I can't see any other obvious issues).

As an aside you should use path patterns to prevent obviously incorrect response descriptors from being tested all the time.

Comment: I have edited the question with data model and modifications on the entity mapping definition. Now juste the AOThreadMessage thread relationship is not set. Other than that, the relationships are correctly set. Can't figure out what the problem is. Regarding the use of path patterns that's a good thing indeed. I'll implement this. Let me know based on the model if relationships are correctly done (i think so, but who knows :))

Comment: The model looks good. The original log shows the messages being connected. If they aren't being used you need to get rid of all of the other response descriptors - you only need one response descriptor to map the thread and all of its nested contents.

Comment: In fact the original log shows the problems before i modified the mapping accordingly to your remarks. I have edited all the son/mapping definition accordingly. Every thing is fine unless the message > thread relation not being done. To be more specific when i first get the thread from the API everything's link. But if in the given thread i post a message (see the edited json) the message is not linked to the thread. Regarding the response descriptors, they are not taken into account for this json since message descripto is on @"response.messages" not on @"response.threads.messages".

Comment: What happens when you post a message? Different JSON is received? What does it contain (a full new definition or a delta change)?

Comment: The json that is in the question is when i post a message. It's a delta for the message objects of a thread

Comment: So by default that should disconnect any existing ones but connect the new ones - please chack that

Comment: So i tested with the full thread being returned after posting and no issue. So the problem is if i return only delta it disconnects all other message unless the one i receive in the json. Is there a way to overcome this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162007/restkit-2-0-mapping-second-entitiy-nil-when-not-unique

Comment: Thank you Wain. You save my put in production schedule.