# RestKit Foreign keys relationship mapping not working

Tags: foreign-keys, mapping, restkit

I have a User object with an attribute followingIds (NSArray - transformable core data type) and a relationship followings to-many

[image: relationships description]

Then in restkit i have the following connection description.

When i check the mappingResult objects the followingIds is set but the relationship is not done. The http response provide a user collection with both user objects; the follower and the followed.

(lldb) po [mappingResult.array firstObject]

```
<AOUser: 0x7feea8ea5940> (entity: AOUser; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-
coredata://E1732DA6-BAEB-4E6E-BC7D-F0944A2CD5B5/AOUser/p1> ; data: {
userId = 2;
follower = "<relationship fault: 0x7feeade18c80 'follower'>";
    followingIds = "(\n    35\n)";
    followings =     (
    );
}
```

(lldb) po [mappingResult.array lastObject]

```
<AOUser: 0x7feeadc0bdf0> (entity: AOUser; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://E1732DA6-BAEB-4E6E-BC7D-F0944A2CD5B5/AOUser/p3> ; data: {
follower = "<relationship fault: 0x7feeade1dae0 'follower'>";
followingIds = "(\n    4\n)";
followings =     (
    "0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://E1732DA6-BAEB-4E6E-BC7D-F0944A2CD5B5/AOUser/p5>"
);
userId = 35;
}
```

EDIT 1:

[image: FOLLOWING]
[image: FOLLOWER]

[image: JSON]

MApping Code

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                         inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"id":                      @"userId",
                                                        @"followingIds":            @"followingIds",
                                                        @"username":                @"username",
                                                        @"email":                   @"email",
                                                        @"profile.pro":             @"pro",
                                                        @"profile.type":            @"type",
                                                        @"profile.country":         @"countryCode",
                                                        @"social.facebook":         @"facebook",
                                                        @"social.youtube":          @"youtube",
                                                        @"social.twitter":          @"twitter",
                                                        @"social.instagram":        @"instagram",
                                                        @"created":                 @"timestamp"
                                                        }];
    entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];

    RKRelationshipMapping *relationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"medias" toKeyPath:@"medias" withMapping:[AOMedia mapping]];
    relationship.assignmentPolicy = RKUnionAssignmentPolicy;
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:relationship];

    relationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"settings" toKeyPath:@"settings" withMapping:[AOSetting mapping]];
    relationship.assignmentPolicy = RKUnionAssignmentPolicy;
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:relationship];

    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"cover" toKeyPath:@"cover" withMapping:[AOMedia mapping]]];
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"avatar" toKeyPath:@"avatar" withMapping:[AOMedia mapping]]];
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"stats" toKeyPath:@"stats" withMapping:[AOUserStat mapping]]];
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"likes" toKeyPath:@"likes" withMapping:[AOLike mapping]]];
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"favorites" toKeyPath:@"favorites" withMapping:[AOFavorite mapping]]];

    [entityMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"followings" connectedBy:@{@"followingIds": @"userId"}];
    [entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];

    return entityMapping;
}
```

Comment: Can't tell anything from this as you haven't shown the mapping code or sample JSON related to the object log. Is the relation many-to-many?

Comment: @wain i have edited as per request

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be because `followingIds` is being stored as a string rather than an array:

```
followingIds = "(\n    35\n)";
```

presumably because RestKit can't tell that you want it as an array because it's simply transformable.

You need to update the code so that the `followingIds` references all state the type as `NSArray` and then RestKit should hopefully maintain the data type from the JSON and match against a list of foreign ids instead of a single (invalid) id.

Comment: But in Core Data followingIds is transformable. (lldb) po [[mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:1] followingIds]
<__NSCFArray 0x7fd383503140>(
4
)

Comment: Ok, could be that's just a logging thing then. Will need to turn on trace logging to see what happens in detail during the foreign key connection. it could also be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162007/restkit-2-0-mapping-second-entitiy-nil-when-not-unique

Comment: I thought about that RKUnionAssignmentPolicy but can't find a way to define assignment policy for addConnectionForRelationship

Comment: Yes, I think this is probably an oversight (a bug) for a relatively uncommon use case in `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation` where assignment policy isn't considered.

Comment: So to overcome this limitation, i shall connect objects manually once mapping is completed? What do you reckon?

Comment: That will be simple, sure. Or you could look at modifying the connection operation to use an assignment policy and raise a pull request.